# Error when creating Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I know there are 2 ways to create a new project in Laravel. One is using `composer create-project laravel/laravel _projectname_` and another is using `laravel new _projectname_`. I tried to create a project using the first one with Composer, and there is no problem with it. But when I tried to create with the second one using `laravel new`, it returned this error:

```
$ laravel new _projectname_
    Crafting application...
    > php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    > php artisan clear-compiled
    Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd  
    event returned with an error


      [RuntimeException]
      Error Output:


    run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [--] [<script>] [<args>]...

    Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

I used Windows as OS and I've set the environment PATH for `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` in PATH, and it works when I try the `laravel` commend in the command prompt. I've always used the `laravel new _projectname_` before and it worked. I think I changed nothing, but it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why. How could that be? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run this in a WAMP setup? I could imagine that would produce some issue if that's the case.

Comment: i run this in Command Prompt, with %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin had been set to the PATH.

Comment: You should consider trying and running this inside a virtual environment. Take a look at this site: https://fideloper.github.io/Vaprobash/

Comment: try `composer self-update` and `composer global update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer, i got from this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cant-use-laravel-new-app-name. Update your laravel using `composer global require "laravel/installer"` . After it finished, tried to run `laravel new _projectname_`, it update all dependencies and it works for me. Hope it helps.